# What is a Servlet Container and how to install one?

Tags: java, linux, solr, servlets

I am about to order a VPS (virtual private server) from a provider, and I guess I have to install some Servlet Container right?

I am about to use SOLR and my website is PHP MYSQL JAVASCRIPT based.

How does an installation of a servlet container work? .exe file?

I am VERY new to servlet containers, so please explain in detail...

Also, how do I know which servlet container I should use?

The VPS OS I will be using is Linux.

Thanks

PS: don't know if this belongs on ServerFault

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A servlet container is basically an **concrete implementation** of the abstract [Servlet API](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/package-summary.html). They are available from several makes: [Oracle Glassfish](https://glassfish.java.net), [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org), [Eclipse Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/), [JBoss AS](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas), etcetera.

A servlet container is normally already programmed in pure java. Thus, basically all you need to do is to have a JRE (sometimes JDK is required instead) already installed. As for any Java software you can basically just download a ZIP from it, it'll contain the servlet container and several startup/shutdown scripts. Or if you're tied to Windows and/or want to install it as a service, some are also available as an EXE. Check the *Downloads* section of the beforelinked server makes in question.

Which one to choose depends on the functional requirement, but I think Apache Tomcat is more than sufficient for your particular purposes. Both Sun Glassfish and JBoss AS are as being full fledged [Java EE API](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/) implementations *much* more than "just" a servlet container.

Tomcat has a quite good "Getting started" documentation: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/index.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you REALLY want to run Solr in Tomcat, they have instructions on their wiki page:  http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat.  But if you are new to Solr I recommend just going with Jetty - see my answer for details.

Comment: So is it possible to have a non-Java servlet container?

Answer (score 3):

Solr is distributed with Jetty.  No installation is required unless you specifically want to run a different container.

You can start Solr within Jetty by `cd`ing to `$SOLR_HOME/example` (where `$SOLR_HOME` is the root of your Solr install) and running `java -jar start.jar`.  This will bring up Solr on port 8983.

You can then test by viewing `http://your.machine.name:8983/solr` (use localhost if the browser is running on the same machine).

Answer (score 1):

> I guess I have to install some Servlet Container right? I am about to use SOLR

Since SOLR requires one, yes, if you don't have one installed already.

> How does an installation of a servlet container work? .exe file?

On Windows, that is one way. I believe msi files are preferred for that sort of thing.

> The VPS OS I will be using is Linux.

Than an exe isn't going to do you much good, since it is the MS DOS / MS Windows executable format. Wikipedia has [a list of servlet containers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Servlet_containers). You need to find one compatible with your OS and read its instructions.

Better yet, since your current knowledge of the subject seems quite low, hire a system administrator with some experience of the platform to help you get started.

Comment: "Since SOLR requires one, yes." - Solr requires a servlet container, but it does not require that you install your own.

Comment: Do you pay for the systems-administrator? Thanks for pointing out but learning it myself is better :)

Comment: If I was at the stage where I was paying for a VPS (rather than an internal development system) then I'd want someone who knew what they were doing on the team rather then depending on my learning as I went along.

Comment: A VPS costs around 30$ a month, hiring a systems-administrator would cost 50 times that a month. I can go on for 50 months and learn it myself (even though it doesn't take that long) and save the money!

Comment: Yes, but if you are at the VPS stage, then presumably you are at the "if it breaks we have real problems" stage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use apache tomcat. It is easy-to-use and reliable. It's one of the mostly used ones.
You can get it from [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/).
It has a very well documentation.